# Rails 5 - Resque not processing enqueued job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, jobs, resque

I'm trying to do enqueue a simple job using `Resque` 1.26.0 (and `Redis-rb` 3.3.1). The job doesn't seem to be processing the `perform` function because `resque-web` is processing each job and shows 0 failures. The jobs also are being processed instantly.

The jobs are enqueued from a controller action with

```
Resque.enqueue(TestJob, url)
```

The job itself looks like

```
class TestJob < ApplicationJob
  @queue = :tags_queue
  Logger.new("log/resque_worker_QUEUE.log").fatal("thing")

  def self.perform(url)
    Logger.new("log/resque_worker_QUEUE.log").fatal("other thing")
    logger.fatal("more errors please")

    myDivideByZeroVar= 1/0
    raise "error"
    Logger.new("log/resque_worker_QUEUE.log").fatal("other thing")
    logger.fatal("more errors please")
  end
end
```

A rake task is also set up:

```
require 'resque/tasks'
task "resque:setup" => :environment
```

The `redis-server` is running.

The worker is started with `rake resque:work QUEUE=*`. Using verbose logging doesn't show anything useful.

The log file only shows the first fatal error string "thing". None of the other errors are logged that are inside `perform`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: In resque web : how much running workers do you have ? Does the processing number increase each time you run the `Resque.enqueue(TestJob, url)` ?

Comment: There is one worker running. The processing number increases each time Resque.enqueue is called, but is processed instantly.

Comment: Did you try to include byebug in the first line of your perform method ?

Comment: Yes. It didn't start the debugger. `perform` isn't being run at all.

Comment: To enable resque as active job adapter we should add  `config.active_job.queue_adapter = :resque` in our rails application configuration (config/application.rb, config/development.rb or config/production.rb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this. The job needed to be called using ActiveJob instead of using `Resque.enqueue`. `TestJob.perform_later(url)` worked just fine.